# Why do the majority of Colorado license plates have Q on them?

Tags: driving, colorado

While road tripping through Colorado, I noticed that a lot of modern (most recent design revision) Colorado license plates...

[image: modern plate]

...had Q on them. Counting 100 plates, 49 did not have Q, 51 did. Q is an odd letter to be on more than 50% of all license plates. Why is this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with travel.

Comment: Thanks to your image, 100% of the Colorado license plates I've seen today did not have a Q on them :)

Comment: Including the one in the question, ironically.

Answer (score 10):

The reason is that from 2013 till 2015, number plates in Colorado were issued in sequential order; from 001-AAQ all the way till 999-ZZQ.

From mid-2015 onwards, common sense prevailed and random combination of letters and numbers were used :-)

Source: the ever-useful [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Colorado).

Comment: Why is a random combination better than sequential numbering?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Why Q?

Comment: @djechlin it answers why there is a Q, not why Q is the letter chosen for the sequence.

Comment: @Sourav , sequential number give away the age of the car (for locals who pay some attention), which makes it easier to identify brand new cars for stealing.

Comment: @djechlin , because Q was unused up to that point of time. Try clicking the given links.

Comment: @Aganju it identifies only the age of the registration.  A ten-year-old newly resold and therefore newly registered car is not likely to be an interesting target.  The better way to identify the age of the car is to look at the car itself.

Comment: @Aganju you should edit the answer to include relevant information from the links then :)

Comment: I think the key part of the linked page that is not described here is that it wasn't that plates were issued in sequential order, it was that all the plates from 2013 to 2015 had at least one Q (emphasis added): "Letter Q not used in serials until early 2013, **when all serials containing at least one of this letter** were issued in alphabetical order following 999-ZZZ (beginning with 001-AAQ and ending with 999-ZZQ)."